# Ranking players and puzzles from performance in a single player game format

Tags: combinatorics, bayesian

I have a 1000 crossword puzzles and a 1000 solvers - each individual is assigned a 100 arbitrary puzzles to solve (so each solver gets exactly 100 puzzles but each puzzle could have 1-1000 solvers) - at the end of the day each we compile a list of (puzzle, solver, time to solve) - based on this info how do you arrange:
A. Puzzles by order of difficulty?
B. Solvers by order of capability?

Further there are situations where Player A has solved Puzzle X in a time shorter than Player B while at the same time Player B has solved Puzzle Y in a time shorter than Player A.

Comment: Actually it is possible some puzzle may not be randomly assigned to any solver.  This sort of "how do you..." Question is probably not the best fit for Math.SE.  You might arrange the puzzles and solvers in a random order as well.  Nothing in the Question's text gives a clear notion of what makes one arrangement preferable to another.

Comment: This question seems appropriate to me, but it's really a statistical question.  As such it's probably more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.com